# Are there important differences between running a program in a IDE and running it by .exe?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2015, executable

My question is quite generic.

I did a mega-giant-project concerning a client-server application on winsock2.

The fact is: my application works perfectly if i open the project in Visual Studio 2015 and i run from there, but if i open the server by double click on his .exe file my client side doesnt display anything.

I won't post the code cause it's like 500 rows, but i am asking: should i take care about something different when i run the program from the .exe? How can i notice if something goes wrong?

P.s. I already debugged from Visual Studio, and it doesn't rise any exception/error when i launch it from .exe (it simply doesn't display anything).
Server is written in C++, client in C#.

UPDATE: It works if i run it from bash, i mean opening cmd.exe. It still doesnt work by double clicking on the .exe. Is it all ok? Can i say i have a working program?

Comment: `How can i notice if something goes wrong?` - Use something like log4net to log everything. Have a logging level in your config that decides what to output. Set the log level to verbose, run your program, read logs.

Comment: *doesnt display anything* and what is it supposed to do instead? Anyway, main difference is the environment in VS is not the same as the global one.

Comment: Working directories are different, which means relative paths are different for files and directories. You might have set some environment variable or command line arguments in the IDE that are not set when double-clicking the executable. You need to make sure you handle errors like that properly, and that you have default values and fallback values available. Also, try running from a console window first, to make sure it works there. Run from different directories. Test it out. And have plenty of logging.

Comment: @stijn I will be more specific, It's a remote assistant application, my client c# should display icons and names of running programs in the server. It works perfectly from vs, tested many times.

Comment: Ok but that does not help us in figuring out what might be the cause. It's your application, tell use *why* it doesn't show icons. What does that mean? Is it not connecting to the server? Is it not finding icon files? Etc. Debug the client: add a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() statement as first line in main, then start by doubleclicking and attach the debugger; you'll be able to debug but not starting with VS which is what you want here

Comment: Ok guys, I solved. It was a retarded error. I created a n.a. .bmp file, which is sent when the server cant extract the icon. I had to move this file in the same directory of the .exe. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer in isolation; *yes* there can be differences, particularly relating to config paths, and some runtime components (winforms in particular has subtle nuances). However! It *sounds* like this is more related to your application. For unhandled errors, you would usually expect *either* a very load crash reported by the OS. But if your code is silently swallowing errors, that wouldn't happen. So, things to check:

- is the exe silently running? check the process list
- do you have big `catch` blocks that aren't reporting the actual problem
- is there anything in the error log?
- are you doing anything specific with stdin that might behave differently?

But the key thing really is to add logging, perhaps behind a compile or command-line switch, that tells you how far it gets.